# additional copy in std::transform when not setting lambda return type

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, copy-elision

I was struggling with the following code sample with gcc 7.3 and c++17:
https://wandbox.org/permlink/UT3RR9jgRmr3VBWv

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

struct Y {
  Y ( int const & s ) : y(s) { std::cout << "construct y\n"; }
  Y ( Y const & yi ) : y(yi.y) { std::cout << "copy y\n"; }
  Y ( Y && yi ) noexcept : y(yi.y) { std::cout << "move y\n"; }
  int y;
};

struct X {
  X ( Y const & yi ) : x(yi.y) { std::cout << "construct x\n"; } 
  X ( X const & xi ) : x(xi.x) { std::cout << "copy x\n"; }
  X ( X && xi ) noexcept : x(xi.x) { std::cout << "move x\n"; }
  int x;
};

int main () {
  std::vector<Y> vy{1};
  std::vector<X> vx;
  vx.reserve(vy.size());
  std::cout << "begin transform\n";
  std::transform(begin(vy), end(vy), std::back_inserter(vx), [] (auto const & y) { return y; });
}
```

The output is

```
construct Y  
copy Y  
begin transform  
copy Y  
construct X  
move X
```

Why does this second copy of Y (in the transform) happen? I can get rid of it by setting the return type of the unary lambda to a reference

```
-> auto const &
```

I thought the inline nature of the lambda operator() and/or copy elision would take care of the "useless" copy.

EDIT: As Barry explained, the answer is that the standard forbids the copy elision of returns of function arguments.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28659879/copy-elision-visible-side-effect

Comment: Why should copy elision apply here?

Comment: Hint: the return type of `[] (Y const & y) { return y; }` is `Y`, not `Y const &`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [copy elision visible side effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28659879/copy-elision-visible-side-effect)

Comment: why is this a possible duplicate? I do not have copy elision for the reasons Barry explained. And this seems like a different answer to me than to the question you linked to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no copy elision from function parameters (see [[class.copy.elision]/1.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.elision#1.1), emphasisis mine):

> This elision of copy/move operations, called copy elision, is permitted in the following circumstances (which may be combined to eliminate multiple copies):
>
> - in a `return` statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of a non-volatile automatic object (**other than a function parameter** or a variable introduced by the exception-declaration of a handler ([except.handle])) with the same type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the function return type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the automatic object directly into the function call's return object

The fact that the lambda is trivial and inlined doesn't matter - that copy is not a candidate for elision. Of course, if the compiler can determine that it can remove the copy under the as-if rule, it could do so - but it cannot in this case because that copy definitely has side effects.